# "Unable To Create Lockable File" Laravel / Azure (App Service)

Tags: laravel, bash, nginx, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I'm receiving an intermittent 500 when making request to my applications APIs:

"Unable to create lockable file: /home/site/wwwroot/storage/framework/cache/data/d1/38/d138002af2c582ff05ad3ca47d0e367ed67f8162. Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location."

Looking at the stack trace, the issue appears to originate from the "ThrottleRequests" middleware.

I suspect that there is a process changing the permissions on the file, preventing the 'ThrottleRequests' class from writing to the cache.

1.) I verified the user performing the write when no error occurs:

```
sh getfileusers.sh /home/site/wwwroot/storage/framework/cache/data/d1/38/d138002af2c582ff05ad3ca47d0e367ed67f8162
```

**getfileusers.sh  contents:**

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=$1

while true; do 
    lsof "${FILE}" 
done > /home/fileusers.log
```

**fileusers.log  contents:**

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME 
php-fpm 14667 www-data   7r   REG  0,104       14 13450135 /home/site/wwwroot/storage/framework/cache/data/d1/38/d138002af2c582ff05ad3ca47d0e367ed67f8162
```

2.) Since the 'www-data' can write with no error I updated my deployment script to ensure other process executing artisan commands are using the www-data user. Relevant lines from deployment script:

**configure scheduler**

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * su www-data -c '/usr/local/bin/php /home/site/wwwroot/artisan schedule:run >> /home/cronresult.txt 2>&1' -s /bin/sh www-data")|crontab
```

**configure supervisor server**

```
echo "[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=/usr/local/bin/php /home/site/wwwroot/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=www-data
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/site/wwwroot/storage/logs/laravel-worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf
```

3.) Other relevant lines from deployment script:

```
php artisan cache:clear
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Does anybody have any insights? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring the cron / supervisor processes created files as the www-data user did the trick.

I was still seeing this issue exactly once after deploying code. Simply changing the order of operations in the deployment script resolved that issue.

Here is my final deployment script. Hopefully it is helpful to someone:

```
echo "[INFO]: Replace nginx config with Laravel specific configuration"
cp /home/site/wwwroot/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

echo "[INFO]: Restarting server . . ."
service nginx reload

echo "[INFO]: Installing 'node' and 'sudo' . . ."
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x -o /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

echo "[INFO]: Executing Application Commands:"
cd /home/site/wwwroot

echo "[INFO]: Turning on maintenance mode . . ."
php artisan down || true

echo "[INFO]: Installing/Updating Composer Dependencies . . ."
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

echo "[INFO]: Clear Cache . . ."
php artisan cache:clear

sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

echo "[INFO]: Clear Expired Password Reset Tokens . . ."
php artisan auth:clear-resets

echo "[INFO]: Clear and Cache Routes . . ."
php artisan route:cache

echo "[INFO]: Clear and Cache Config . . ."
php artisan config:cache

echo "[INFO]: Clear and Cache Views . . ."
php artisan view:cache

echo "[INFO]: Running 'npm install' . . ."
npm install

echo "[INFO]: Running 'npm run build' . . ."
npm run build

echo "[INFO]: Turning off maintenance mode . . ."
php artisan up

echo "[INFO]: Install 'cron'"
## configure cron ##
apt-get update -qq && apt-get install cron -yqq

apt-get install sudo

(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * su www-data -c '/usr/local/bin/php /home/site/wwwroot/artisan schedule:run >> /home/cronresult.txt 2>&1' -s /bin/sh www-data")|crontab

service cron start

echo "[INFO]: Install and configure 'supervisor'"
## configure supervisor ##
apt-get install -y supervisor

#Create supervisor configuration file
touch /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf

# Add contents to Supervisor configuration file
echo "[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=/usr/local/bin/php /home/site/wwwroot/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=www-data
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/site/wwwroot/storage/logs/laravel-worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600" >> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf

service supervisor start
supervisorctl reload
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*

echo "[INFO]: Deployment Complete !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
```